# ANR in activity for broadcast of Intents

Tags: android

I keep getting this error. Can anyone tell me what it means or how i fix it? 
Thanks

07-03 08:27:13.615: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): ANR in com.fttech.books

07-03 08:27:13.615: ERROR/ActivityManager(61): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x40000004 (has extras) }

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ANR stands for "Application not responding". This message means that your application isn't responsive to the user anymore. Normally this exception is thrown if the UI thread is blocked by an operation that takes more than 5 seconds. [Here are some information on this topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).

> Android applications normally run entirely on a single (i.e. main) thread. This means that anything your application is doing in the main thread that takes a long time to complete can trigger the ANR dialog because your application is not giving itself a chance to handle the input event or Intent broadcast.

So check your code if you're doing any long-running operations on the UI thread.

Comment: And note that `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread.

Comment: Thanks! So ive figured it out. In my Query in my SQL database. I left out two very important columns that the query needed but didnt give any syntax. So once i added those BAM! so i did what you did and commented out each method at a time to see what the problem was. and sure i enough it was that.

Comment: Would starting an IntentService be a long-running operation on the UI thread?  'Cause that's what I'm doing in my onReceive() method.

Comment: Is it normal to receive this error when debugging the onReceive() method in an object of a class derived from AppWidget within Android Studio?

Comment: But I just saving boolean value on sharedpreference. Is it the reason of ANR?

Answer (score 1):

Flo is totally right in its explanation of the issue. 
In my case setting some Breakpoints in the *onReceive()* method and trying to start an Activity with an Intent caused the debug to be broken. I can perfectly reproduce the issue.

The solution is to disable all breakpoints and set them at the start of the new Activity, or if you need to debug *onReceive()*, log what happens there with *[Log()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)* function.

There could be also other errors in the code that may break the debug.

Comment: thanks for the corrections BADSHAH :)